# How to use CANOpen PDO?

Tags: networking, pdo, can-bus, canopen

I am trying to send data from TMS320F28335 to EPOS2 24/5 driver of Maxon Motor using CANOpen.
Previously, I used only SDO Protocol on velocity mode. But now I try to use PDO Protocol.
I refer to Fig. 1. to use velocity mode with SDO protocol.
PDO requires 'Mapping', 'RPDO', 'TPDO'...
It makes me complicate.

## **First question**

[image: Fig. 1. Velocity Mode]

I read datasheet of Maxon Motor. 'PDO Mapping' requires NMT state 'Pre-Operational Mode'.

**From above figure, should I implement 'PDO Mapping' before NMT state 'Set Operational Mode'?**

## **Second question**

I use TPDO1, RTDO1 because I only want to acquire velocity of motor and send target velocity value to motor driver.

The first object of TPDO1 is 'Statusword'(index : 0x1A00, sub-index : 0x01, value : 0x60410010).

The second object of TPDO1 is 'Velocity Actual Value'(index : 0x1A00, sub-index : 0x02, value : 0x606C0020)

The first object of RPDO1 is 'Controlword'(index : 0x1600, sub-index : 0x01, value : 0x60400010).

The second object of RPDO1 is  'Target Velocity'(index : 0x1600, sub-index : 0x02, value : 0x60FF0020)

And then I send 'Set Operation Mode' packet to motor driver and send 'Shutdown', 'Enable' command as can be seen from figure 1.

**After 'shutdown', 'enable' I don't know what to do next.**

## **Third question**

[image: Fig. 2.]

From figure 2, 'Operational Mode' can be done using 'Start Remote Node' command.
Then if 'Operational Mode' could be done by 'Start Remote Node' in NMT Protocol, how to set 'Velocity Mode' after 'Start Remote Node'?

**Are there two methods to set 'Operational Mode'?**

1. Send '0x6060-00', '0xFE' in 'Set Operational Mode' step.
2. Use 'Start Remote Node' method of NMT Protocol.

**If there are two methods, how to set the velocity mode in second method?**

Comment: "I don't know how to proceed with PDO protocol after 'Shutdown', 'Enable'." I don't understand what you mean with that.

Comment: Other than that, the answer to question #1 is "yes" and the answer to #3 is that you are confusing operational modes of your application with operational modes of the CANopen bus. There is only one way to start a node and thats with NMT start remote node.

Comment: @Lundin I edit the second question. You mean that 'operational modes of application(velocity, profile position etc...)' and 'operational modes of the CANOpen bus' are different each other?

Comment: Yes, your application-specific stuff is just a payload, it has nothing to do with CANopen or NMT. Unless you are using a standardized Device Profile, in which case there are certain default rules, default mappings etc to follow.

Comment: As a rule, do not ask more than one question in a single question post.